# Keras- Weighted binary cross entropy for bninary multilabel classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am working on multilabel binary classification task. Dataset have 5 labels each have value 0 or 1. The dataset is highly imbalanced with 94% and 6% ratio. Working with Keras, I have used binary cross entropy loss function but I want to assign higher weights to class having lower frequency. I have searched [Keras: weighted binary crossentropy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009619/keras-weighted-binary-crossentropy#) but it is for binary classification problem. Can I use this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits for this kind of problem?